# How can praat get formant data from audio?

Tags: mfcc, lpc, praat, acoustics

I'm making a program that extracts formants similar to praat. However, when I applied both lpc and mfcc, I don't think the accuracy is as good as praat. How can I extract the formant exactly like praat?

I kept changing the lpc order to 80, 30, 70, etc. to test whether the formant was extracted similarly to praat, but it didn't come out well. I also experimented with changing the number of mfcc filters in mfcc, but it doesn't seem to come out well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.